# UITableViewController and pushing a DetailViewController on it

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController and want to push a DetailViewController : UIViewController. Do I need to make the UITableViewController be part of a UINavigationController or can I just do a pushViewController from a UITableViewController?

I understand that UINavigationController (and UITabBarController) have a viewController's array that manages the viewing of view controllers. Does a UITableViewController have the same?

Sorry if question sounds convoluted.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a navigation stack where you can push and pop view controllers, you want the UINavigationController.

The easiest way to do it would be to place your UITableViewController into the UINavigationController (assuming that it is the first screen displayed) and then you can do a simple push from the controller.  It would look something like this:

```
// First create viewController and then push it like this:
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```